# Shell script: Count files, delete 'X' oldest file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to scripting. Currently I have a script that backs up a directory every day to a file server. It deletes the oldest file outside of 14 days. My issue is I need it to count the actual files and delete the 14th oldest one. When going by days, if the file server or host is down for a few days or longer, when back up it will delete a couple days worth of backups or even all of them. Pending down time. I want it to always have 14 days worth of backups.

I tried searching around and could only find solutions related to deleting by dates. Like what I have now.

Thank you for the help/advice!

My code I have, sorry its my first attempt at scripting:

```
#! /bin/sh

#Check for file. If not found, the connection to the file server is down!
if 
[ -f /backup/connection ];
then
echo "File Server is connected!"

#Directory to be backed up.
backup_source="/var/www/html/moin-1.9.7"
#Backup directory.
backup_destination="/backup"
#Current date to name files.
date=`date '+%m%d%y'`
#naming the file.
filename="$date.tgz"

echo "Backing up directory"

#Creating the back up of the backup_source directory and placing it into the backup_destination directory.
tar -cvpzf $backup_destination/$filename $backup_source
echo "Backup Finished!"

#Search for folders older than '+X' days and delete them.
find /backup -type f -ctime +13 -exec rm -rf {} \;

else
echo "File Server is NOT connected! Date:`date '+%m-%d-%y'` Time:`date '+%H:%M:%S'`" > /user/Desktop/error/`date '+%m-%d-%y'`
fi
```

Comment: You might be interested in [rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org/). It uses rsync and is more efficient than your solution. The config file has a parameter `retain`, if you set `retain 14` it will always keep the last 14 backups.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines like this might work:

```
ls -1t /path/to/directory/ | head -n 14 | tail -n 1
```

in the ls command, -1 is to list just the filenames (nothing else), -t is to list them in chronological order (newest first).  Piping through the head command takes just the first 14 from the output of the ls command, then tail -n 1 takes just the last from that list.  This should give the the file that is 14th newest.

Comment: Thank you that worked on finding the 14th file. I have tried a few things out on adding to that line of code. I want to be able to delete the selected file. I tried adding -exec rm -rf {} \: to the end and that did not work. I tried |xargs rm at the end and it seems it could work, it just didn't do anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try | xargs rm -rf    If you have the necessary permissions to delete the file, that should work.

Comment: So I have: ls -1t /user/Desktop/testDir | head -n 14 | tail -n 1 | xargs rm -rf and run through just fine but doesn't actually delete the file or tell me what file it is. I changed the permissions on the directory to 777 to see if that was it. But still nothing. Thank you for your patients and help!

Comment: I tested on one of my systems, and it worked.  I'm wondering if the filename of the file that it's trying to delete contains spaces or some other characters that are causing a problem.  As a test, try  ls -1t /user/Desktop/testDir | head -n 14 | tail -n 1 | xargs echo   This should show you the name of the file that it's trying to delete.  What does it show?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another suggestion. The following script simply enumerates the backups. This eases the task of keeping track of the last *n* backups. If you need to know the actual creation date you can simply check the file metadata, e.g. using `stat`.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

backup_source='somedir'
backup_destination='backup'
retain=14
filename="backup-$retain.tgz"

check_fileserver() {
  nc -z -w 5 file.server.net 80 2>/dev/null || exit 1
}

backup_advance() {
  if [ -f "$backup_destination/$filename" ]; then
    echo "removing $filename"
    rm "$backup_destination/$filename"
  fi

  for i in $(seq $(($retain)) -1 2); do
    file_to="backup-$i.tgz"
    file_from="backup-$(($i - 1)).tgz"

    if [ -f "$backup_destination/$file_from" ]; then
      echo "moving $backup_destination/$file_from to $backup_destination/$file_to"
      mv "$backup_destination/$file_from" "$backup_destination/$file_to"
    fi
  done
}

do_backup() {
  tar czf "$backup_destination/backup-1.tgz" "$backup_source"
}

check_fileserver
backup_advance
do_backup

exit 0
```

Comment: Thank you both mti and Marco, both methods are working for me now. Now that I have it running and working properly, I want to recreate it in C++. Do you think that would be a difficult task? I will post my script here shortly, and hopefully also my c++ coding if I can get that to work like the script does now!

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite it in a compiled language? It's surely not difficult, but why? I can't think of a single advantage, but there are many disadvantages (less portable, change requires recompilation, every sysadmin knows shell scripts, not all know C++, additional work, new code/bugs, etc). I you want to have it faster, use rsync or install `rsnapshot` since it already does all the work you're trying to reimplement yourself.

Comment: No particular reason, just trying to learn my friend. I find it interesting to see how I would get the same result (backup script) from multiple methods. But yes I see where your coming from with all the disadvantages. It's nice to actually see the advantages and disadvantages be actually building them. I'm a hands on/visual learner. Thank you for the input!